# access both wireless and wired networks?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a friend whose company restricts so many websites that he can't find the answers to the programming problems he needs to do his job. (I.e. He says that all blogs are somehow blocked)  But his company also has a wireless network that is unrestricted (don't ask me the logic of this) I was thinking he could install a virtual machine that is connected to the wireless network but have his host OS connected to the wired network (he needs some resources that are only on the wired network) Would that work?  Is there maybe a simpler solution, I.e. Just tell the browser to use the wireless network somehow?

Comment: Just a small caution: It is possible that this will get your friend fired, as lame as their rules are.

Comment: It's stories like this that remind me to be thankful of the job I have

Answer (score 2):

> Just tell the browser to use the
>   wireless network somehow?

This might be of interest:

**[ForceBindIP - Bind any Windows application to a specific interface](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/)**

> ForceBindIP is a freeware Windows
>   application that will inject itself
>   into another application and alter how
>   certain Windows Sockets calls are
>   made, allowing you to force the other
>   application to use a specific network
>   interface / IP address. This is useful
>   if you are in an environment with
>   multiple interfaces and your
>   application has no such option for
>   binding to a specific interface.

Answer (score 0):

Does he have access to the route table? He could set up custom routes for the resources that are only available on the wired network and set the default route to the wireless network.

What operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Most virtual machine managers will allow you to bind a specific interface card to a specific virtual machine (VirtualBox as an example). He should know that having both of these networks attached to the same machine completely voids the advantage of having separate networks. A VM makes it more difficult, but the danger is still high.